# Eventlistener preUpdate embedded Form

Tags: symfony, event-listener, symfony-2.2

I have an preUpdate Eventlistener on an Entitychild in my embedded Form.

I can change the attribute related to my entity:

```
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{   
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof AOSupplierReference) {
        if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('amount')) {

            $entity->setConfirmed(false);

        }
    }
}
```

But now I have to change an attribute of the parent Entity, this don't work in my preUpdate event:

```
$entity->getPurchaseOrder()->setStatus(4);
```

only the $entity->setConfirmed(false) changes.

Comment: Can you change the parent's value in your controller, prior to binding the form?

Comment: yes, but that is not my goal, because it depends on the preUpdate Child action, if I set the status of the purchaseOrder to 4. Furthermore I have access to the getPurchaseOrder() methods but the setStatus(4) is not set in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't update a related entity in a preUpdate listener**:

> PreUpdate is the most restrictive to use event, since it is called
>   right before an update statement is called for an entity inside the
>   EntityManager#flush() method.
>
> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in
>   this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle
>   referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.

See the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/events.html#preupdate).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i fixed my problem now in another way